# How to remove the keys of a dictionary where the values are null in swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

Hi I need to remove the dictionary keys which is having no values .I tried many codes but  not working .I only need the dictionary with keys which have values and I need to do it in swift 3

```
["H": [], "X": [], "D": ["D1\r\n\r\n"], "J": ["J1\r\n"], "I": [], "M": [], "Z": [], "S": [], "A": ["A2"], "C": ["C2\r\n\r\n"], "N": [], "Y": [], "R": [], "G": [], "E": ["Emmm\r\n"], "V": [], "U": [], "L": [], "B": ["B2"], "K": ["King"], "F": [], "O": [], "W": [], "T": ["Test", "Test2"], "P": [], "Q": ["Queen"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this code and worked for me.

```
var dict: [String: [Any]] = ["H": [], "X": [], "D": ["D1\r\n\r\n"], "J": ["J1\r\n"], "I": [], "M": [], "Z": [], "S": [], "A": ["A2"], "C": ["C2\r\n\r\n"], "N": [], "Y": [], "R": [], "G": [], "E": ["Emmm\r\n"], "V": [], "U": [], "L": [], "B": ["B2"], "K": ["King"], "F": [], "O": [], "W": [], "T": ["Test", "Test2"], "P": [], "Q": ["Queen"]]
for (key, value) in dict where value.isEmpty {
   dict.removeValue(forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `if value.isEmpty` instead, which is more readable. You could put the condition into the loop as well: `for (key, value) in dict where value.isEmpty { dict.removeValue(forKey: key) }`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe edited answer as per comment. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant "remove the KVPs that have `[]` as values", not "remove the KVPs that have `nil` as values".

A call to `filter` would work, but it returns an array of tuples of KVPs so you gotta add them all to a new dictionary using a for loop.

```
let dict = ["H": [], "X": [], "D": ["D1\r\n\r\n"], "J": ["J1\r\n"], "I": [], "M": [], "Z": [], "S": [], "A": ["A2"], "C": ["C2\r\n\r\n"], "N": [], "Y": [], "R": [], "G": [], "E": ["Emmm\r\n"], "V": [], "U": [], "L": [], "B": ["B2"], "K": ["King"], "F": [], "O": [], "W": [], "T": ["Test", "Test2"], "P": [], "Q": ["Queen"]]
var newDict = [String: [String]]()
for (key, value) in dict.filter({ !$0.1.isEmpty }) {
    newDict[key] = value
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this by just looping through the dictionary once:

```
let dict = ["H": [], "X": [], "D": ["D1\r\n\r\n"], "J": ["J1\r\n"], "I": [], "M": [], "Z": [], "S": [], "A": ["A2"], "C": ["C2\r\n\r\n"], "N": [], "Y": [], "R": [], "G": [], "E": ["Emmm\r\n"], "V": [], "U": [], "L": [], "B": ["B2"], "K": ["King"], "F": [], "O": [], "W": [], "T": ["Test", "Test2"], "P": [], "Q": ["Queen"]]
var newDict = [String: [String]]()
for (key, value) in dict where !value.isEmpty {
    newDict[key] = value
}
```